# Column titles not appearing in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

Any thoughts as to why the following code would display column titles?  I have tried with and without a scollpane.

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
contentPane = new JPanel();
contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
setContentPane(contentPane);
contentPane.setLayout(null);

JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);

contentPane.add(scrollpane, "wrap, span");

tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"Name","Instrument Type","Channel","Number of Channels"},0);



table = new JTable();
table.setBounds(6, 6, 697, 172);
tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"Fixture Name","Fixture Type","Fixture Channel","Number of Channels"},0);
        table.setModel(tableModel);
        contentPane.add(table);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use a layout manager
2. Add the scroll pane to the frame, not the table...

You're code snippet is either missing it, or you example is wrong.

```
JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
```

This either means you've already created the table, in which case, you're double creating it, or it's going to generate a `NullPointerException`

Your code should look more like...

```
table = new JTable();
tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"Fixture Name","Fixture Type","Fixture Channel","Number of Channels"},0);
table.setModel(tableModel);
contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(table));
```

Have a look through [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

```
tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"Fixture Name","Fixture Type","Fixture   Channel","Number of Channels"},0);
    table.setModel(tableModel);
    contentPane.add(table); // This is the place that is creating problem for you.
```

While adding just add the JTable to the JScrollPane and add the scrollpane to the container like the following,

```
    **contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(table));**
```

See @Dan post for [why to use a JScrollPane.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670844/jtable-doesnt-show-columns-names)