# I am not getting names of column

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, jtableheader

I am placing a `JTable` in a `JPanel`, but when I am displaying, I see the table contents but not the column names.

```
public class Neww extends JPanel
{
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement st;
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {
        { " ", " " },
        { " ", " " },
        { " ", " " },
        { " ", " " },
        { " ", " " },
        { " ", " " }
    }, new Object[] {
        "ItemName",
        "No of items"
    });

    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    TableColumn ItemName = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
    Neww()
    {
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        this.add(table);

        comboBox.addItem("Spoon");
        comboBox.addItem("Plate");
        comboBox.addItem("Mixer");
        comboBox.addItem("Glass");
        ItemName.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

there are two ways

- (proper of ways) have to put `JTable` to the `JScrollPane`, then `JTableHeader` is visible
- get `JTableHeader` from `JTable` (change `JPanel`s `LayoutManager` to `BorderLayout`) and put to `NORTH area` in `JPanel`

Answer (score 2):

1) Wrap your `JTable` within `JScrollPane`. Like this:

```
JTable table=...;

JPanel container = new JPanel();

JScrollPane jsp=new JScrollPane(table);

container.add(jsp);
```

2) Use `getTableHeader()` and add it where needed (usually north positioned though):

```
...

JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();

JPanel container = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

// Add header at NORTH position
container.add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);

//Add table below header
container.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 1):

Following statement is creating problem in your code.

```
 this.add(table);
```

Use scroll pane while adding table.

```
 add(new JScrollPane(table));
```

Why should we use `JScrollPane`?

As stated by @OscarRyz in this [comment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320812/jtable-wont-show-column-headers)

> The table header it put into the JScrollPane top component ( or top
>   view or something like that is named ) When there is no top component
>   the JTable appears headless. This is by design.

**Edit:** Also look this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935934/java-jtable-column-headers-not-showing/13936925#13936925) for more details.