# Java JTable Column headers not showing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, jtableheader

My code (Logic-wise) is all good, the only problem is that the column headers do not show up in the 2 tables (table and tableS, one for teacher and one for student details). How do I make them show?

```
        import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Display
{
    ArrayList<Student> stud1 = new ArrayList<Student>();
    ArrayList<SubjectTeacher> sTeach1 = new ArrayList<SubjectTeacher>();

    //For Display Teachers
    private  JTable table;
    private  JFrame f;
    private int i;

    //For DisplayStudents
    private JTable tableS;
    private JFrame fS;
    private int iS;


    //Displays Teachers
    public void displayTeachers()
    {

            f = new JFrame("Teachers");

            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setSize(500,400);
            f.setVisible(true);



        String[] columnNames =  {"Name", "Surname", "ID", "Pay", "Subject"};

        sTeach1 = Stores.getTeach();
        i = sTeach1.size();


        Object[][] data = new Object[i+1][5];



            for (int j = 0; j<sTeach1.size(); j++)
            {
                {
                    SubjectTeacher myTeach = sTeach1.get(j);
                     data[j][0] = myTeach.getName();
                     data[j][1] = myTeach.getSurname();
                     data[j][2] = myTeach.getID();
                     data[j][3] = myTeach.getPay();
                     data[j][4] = myTeach.getSubjectID();
                };
            }




    JTable table = new JTable (data, columnNames);
    f.add(table);

    }



    //Displays Students
    public void displayStudents()
    {

        System.out.println(stud1.size());

            fS = new JFrame("Students");

            fS.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            fS.setSize(700,600);
            fS.setVisible(true);



        String[] colNames =  {"Name", "Surname", "ID", "Computer", "Physics", "Maths", "Tests", "Passes", "Fails"};


        stud1 = Stores.getStud();
        iS = stud1.size();

        Object[][] info = new Object[iS+1][9];




        for (int j = 0; j<stud1.size(); j++)
            {
                {


                    Student myStud = stud1.get(j);

                 info[j][0] = myStud.getName();
                 info[j][1] = myStud.getSurname();
                 info[j][2] = myStud.getID();
                 info[j][3] = myStud.getSubject(1);
                 info[j][4] = myStud.getSubject(2);
                 info[j][5] = myStud.getSubject(3);
                 info[j][6] = myStud.getTestsTaken();
                 info[j][7] = myStud.getPasses();
                 info[j][8] = myStud.getFails();
                };
            }




    JTable tableS = new JTable (info, colNames);
    fS.add(tableS);

    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JTable won't show column headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320812/jtable-wont-show-column-headers)

Answer (score 21):

Here is the problem.

```
JTable table = new JTable (data, columnNames);
f.add(table);
```

Do not add the table directly. Use `JScrollPane` to show the table headers.

```
f.add(new JScrollPane(table))
```

Why do you need to put the table in the `JScrollPane`?

From [@Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12671160/230513) post:

> When you put the component inside the constructor of a `JScrollPane`, you mention which is the view to which the scroll to be applied for.
>
> On the other side, using the add method, you just add a component to a container, like adding it to a `JPanel`. This way, you don't specify the component to add the scroll bars to.

**EDIT:**
From [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#show) (cited by trashgod in the comment section)

> Here is typical code for creating a scroll pane that serves as a
>   container for a table:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
```

> The two lines in this snippet do the following:
>   The JScrollPane constructor is invoked with an argument that refers to
>   the table object. This creates a scroll pane as a container for the
>   table; the table is automatically added to the container.
>   JTable.setFillsViewportHeight is invoked to set the
>   fillsViewportHeight property. When this property is true the table
>   uses the entire height of the container, even if the table doesn't
>   have enough rows to use the whole vertical space. This makes it easier
>   to use the table as a drag-and-drop target. The scroll pane
>   automatically places the table header at the top of the viewport. The
>   column names remain visible at the top of the viewing area when the
>   table data is scrolled.
>
> If you are using a table without a scroll pane, then you must get the
>   table header component and place it yourself. For example:

```
container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
container.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
container.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: See also [*Adding a Table to a Container*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#show).

Answer (score 4):

If I remember correctly, you should put a container (e.g. a `JScrollPane`) around it.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is Eclipse or the plugin I use (Jigloo), but I can just rightclick the table and choose for "Surround by container". This link should set you on your way regardless: http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/ScrollableJTable.shtml

Comment: thanks the thing is im using JCreator (no help or pre made graphics) since this is for a project

Comment: It is as easy as `fS.add(new JScrollPane(tableS));`

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I set my `JFrame` layout to `null` `(f.setLayout(null))`. So when I removed it and added

```
f.add(new JScrollPane(table)).
```

It worked.