# JTable and JScrollPane issue

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, jscrollpane

```
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
panel.add(scrollPane);
```

The `scrollPane` is not visible. If I add the

```
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
```

What do you think did I miss in the code? Because of I didn't put the

```
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
```

the `JTable` layout is not fitting on my `panel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing this,

```
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
```

Specify Dimension like this,

```
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(400, 60));
```

**UPDATE:**

I think the above stated answer is not a good approach. You should never use `setXXSize` methods on a component. So please use this [appraoch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971089/jtable-inside-jscrollpane-best-height-to-disable-scrollbars/13974131#13974131) stated by @Kleopatra to set the Viewport size.

Comment: @mKorbel :) Please my friend can you tel me why?

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the answer. Aaah Now I guess the down_vote you told could be coming from @Kleopatra .. :-)