# Resizing the height of JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, swingworker, jtableheader

I'm trying to obtain square ( cells with the same width and height )
However I can only resize the width with the method setPreferredWidth like this:

```
TableColumnModel tcm = table1.getColumnModel();
tcm.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(100);
```

I tried to  use the method `setPreferredSize(100,100);` but it doesn't work and I tried the method `setRowHeight(100);` but it still does not work... I'm using an internal frame, I don't know if it is the reason setRowHeight doesn't work.
How can I do?

Comment: setRowHeight should do the trick... have you tried calling it after loading the table model?

Comment: I didn't use a table model, what I did was: I created a class that inherits JInternalFrame. Then I created a table like this 
String[] data = {
{"1","2","3","4"}......
}
String[] cols = {"Col 1", "Col 2","Col 3", "Col 4"};
public JTable table1 = new JTable(data, cols); 
and within the constructor I set SetRowHeight(100); but it didn't work

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: here is my code:
class ShowEmployee extends JInternalFrame {

    String[][] data = {
      {"1", "2", "3","4"},
         {"5", "6", "7","8"},
         {"9","10","11","12"},
         {"13","14","15","16"}
         };
    String[] cols = {"Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3","Col 4"};

    public JTable table = new JTable(data, cols);
   
    public ShowEmployee() {

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);

        getContentPane().add(scroll);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setRowHeight(100);}}

Comment: 1) Tip: Add @ammoQ (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. 2) Don't post code in comments, instead [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30051047/edit). 3) An uncompilable code snippet is not an MCVE.  Post an *MCVE* as an edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can override [`getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getPreferredScrollableViewportSize--) like they show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13974131/261156) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14429388/261156).

```
private static int N = …;
…
JTable table = new JTable() {

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
        Dimension dim = new Dimension(
            table.getRowHeight() * N,
            table.getRowHeight() * N);
        return dim;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it still resizing width !

Answer (score 1):

Don't extend JInternalFrame. You have NOT added any new functionality to that class. Instead you create a JInternalFrame and you add the scroll pane to the internal frame.

```
setRowHeight(100);
```

The `setRowHeight(...)` is a method of JTable so you need to use `table.setRowHeight(100)`. Also, this method should be invoked when you create the table, not after the internal frame is visible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have to use iJIternalFrame to make 2 JTables in the same JFrame.

Comment: I didn't say you couldn't use a JInternalFrame. I said you should NOT `extend` JInternalFrame.