# Difference between JScrollPane.setviewportview vs JScrollPane.add

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I faced this new thing today, and I didn't know why. When I want to show something in panel for example, I just add it to panel; but why I cannot add a table to scroll pane directly, and why I have to call the `setviewportview()` method? What does `add()` method do and what does `setViewProtView()` do?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Basically, you should not use `JScrollPane#add`.

`JScrollPane` has a single component already attached to it, a `JViewport`, this is what the `JScrollPane` uses to display any component added to the view port.

[image]

`setViewportView` is a convenience method for for `JScrollPane#getViewport#setView`

The basic concept comes down to the fact that from the scroll panes point of view, it will only show a single component, so `add` doesn't actually make any sense for it.  The method is a consequence of extending from `JComponent` -> `Container`

Comment: Great answer. I found several answers pointing to use setViewPortView, but no one explained like you did here - 1.  basically JScrollpane already has a component called Viewport, 2. add is just redundant method came through inheritance! Thanks for explaining it nicely.

Comment: Why couldn't JScrollPane#add be overridden to behave as expected?

Comment: @gdbj You'd have to ask the original framework developers, but, `add` comes from `java.awt.Container`, so it's inheritance issue