# JScrollPane in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I want to write a simple Java program, which consists of a `JFrame` that integrates a **`JScrollPane`.** Just it does not work the way I do it.

What is the issue of the my approach ?

```
public class TestView {

    JFrame frame;
    JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public TestView(){

        frame = new JFrame();
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();    
        scrollPane.add(new JLabel("Klick me"));
        scrollPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200,200));

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        frame.setSize(200,200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void createAndShowGui(){
        TestView tv = new TestView();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
```

Comment: what did you expect?what is not working?? you haven't add anything to jscroll pane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the issue is that you do not see your label in the scrollpane, you might need to use

`scrollpane.setViewportView(new JLabel("Klick me"));`

instead of

`scrollPane.add(new JLabel("Klick me"));`

Additionally, I suggest you create a `JPanel`, give it a layout, and place your label there, instead of passing the label to the scrollpane. Then set this panel as the viewport.

Please see

### [Difference between JscrollPane.setviewportview vs JscrollPane.add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138111/difference-between-jscrollpane-setviewportview-vs-jscrollpane-add)

Answer (score 1):

use for example:

```
final JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
myPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));  
final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(myPanel);
```

setMinimumSize will be ignored.

Comment: See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)