# Why is my table not showing column names?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

[image]

```
String[] i2ColumnNames = {"Sr. No."
                          "Head ID",
                          "Name",
                          "Category",
                          "Financial Year",
                          "Debit",
                          "Credit"};
```

Comment: post the full code to get help.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320812/jtable-wont-show-column-headers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
i2t1sp1 = new JScrollPane(i2Table1);
layout.row().left().add(i2Table1);
```

You need to replace this line:

```
 layout.row().left().add(i2Table1);
```

by this one:

```
layout.row().left().add(i2t1sp1);
```

You're not adding the scroll pane but the table directly to the [layout](https://designgridlayout.java.net/usage.html).

#### Off topic

Always follow [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf). Variables must have meaningful names.

Comment: i2t1sp1 = internal frame 2.. table 1... scrollpane1.
Thanks for the info. it worked and 1 more question.. is there any code  to change the view of the internal frames. they look lame.

Comment: I never would have guessed. @Toms

Comment: hehe.. dic. I am doing my final year project. Can the designs of internal frames be changed? If you have time, please can you go through my way of coding and suggest improvements on my style of coding. i am just a newbie, if you can put ur email id here, i will mail u the code.

Comment: All swing components "look" depends on the [Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/) (see the link for more details). Java has a default cross-platform L&F also called Metal, and yes, internal frames look pretty bad. My best advice is please start using an IDE such as [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/keplersr1) or [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/downloads/). Your coding style isn't bad, you just need to keep in mind that anyone who reads your code must be able to understand it. See code conventions! @Toms