# Table Header is not displaying on Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

I add full code Here. Check the following code which I am using to create the table. 
While executing the program, Values are displaying clearly, but the header is not displaying.

```
public class Table extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JFrame f;
    JPanel p1;
    JPanel jPanel1;
    JTable jTable1;

    Table() {

        f=new JFrame("Home123");
        f.setSize(getMaximumSize());
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(null);

        p1=new JPanel();
        p1.setBackground(Color.red);
        p1.setVisible(true);
        p1.setLayout(null);
        f.add(p1);

        String[] headers = {"First Name","Last Name","Age"};
        Object[][] data = {
        {"Kathy", "Smith",new Integer(25)},
        };  

         jTable1 =new JTable(data, headers);
         JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTable1);

         p1.add(jTable1);

         p1.setBounds(200, 100, 500, 500);
         jTable1.setBounds(70,250, 375,80);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
                new Table();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you put the JTable in JScrollPane

Comment: read Oracle tutorial - How to use Tables for working code examples

Comment: Ya I use JScrollPane also..

Comment: Welcome to SO. May be this [SO-link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320812/jtable-wont-show-column-headers) help you.

Comment: You code does not compile. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class TableExample extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

        JFrame f;
        JPanel p1;
        JPanel jPanel1;
        JTable jTable1;

        TableExample() {

            JFrame f;
        JPanel p1;
        JPanel jPanel1;
        JTable jTable1;

        f = new JFrame("Home123");
        f.setSize(getMaximumSize());

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setBackground(Color.red);
        p1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.add(p1);

        String[] headers = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Age"};
        Object[][] data = {
            {"Kathy", "Smith", new Integer(25)},};

        jTable1 = new JTable(data, headers);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTable1);
        scrollPane.setSize(500,500);
        jTable1.setSize(500,500);
        p1.add(scrollPane);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TableExample();
            }
        });
        }

        @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                System.out.println("");

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

try this its working and showing all thing that u need.[image]

Comment: in mine case its working dont know what is the prob with your way of doing it. wait.

Comment: look the screen shot what i am getting.

Comment: @mKorbel what u trying to say?

Comment: three important mistakes, isn't it :-)

Comment: @Krishna.. If i use p1.setVisible(true);.. Table displaying, otherwise it not displaying...

Comment: @Krishna see my answer here, I'm hope that explain more

Comment: @ShajiSS according to me u adding main panel as p1 so if u add it in content pane of main frame then and then it will show content na isnt it?

Comment: @mKorbel okey i got your point brother. that u have run code in Thread and ya u have maintain important thing that is about panel about not need to set it visible it will be by default.

Answer (score 4):

to @Sergiy Medvynskyy and @Krishna about 1. `f.setVisible(true);` 2. `Initial Thread` 3. `p1.setVisible(true);`

e.g.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class Table /*extends JFrame implements ActionListener*/ {

    private JFrame f;
    private JPanel p1;
    private JPanel jPanel1;
    private JTable jTable1;

    public Table() {
        p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setBackground(Color.red);
        p1.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));        
        String[] headers = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Age"};
        Object[][] data = {
            {"Kathy", "Smith", new Integer(25)},};        
        jTable1 = new JTable(data, headers);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTable1);
        jTable1.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(jTable1.getPreferredSize());
        p1.add(scrollPane);        
        f = new JFrame("Home123");
        //f.setSize(getMaximumSize());
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(p1);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Table();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i was too lazy to check whether the code can be at least compiled

Comment: @Sergiy Medvynskyy reason why I'm leaving to answer and questions here, hmmmm and my endless lazyness is top one of reasons

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the table directly to the frame's panel, instead of adding the scroll pane wrapping the table, and displaying the headers.

Change

```
p1.add(jTable1);
```

to

```
p1.add(scrollPane);
```

And definitely stop using a null layout and setting bounds. Learn using layout managers.

Answer (score 1):

You should add scroll pane to panel

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class Table extends JFrame {
    JFrame f;
    JPanel p1;
    JPanel jPanel1;
    JTable jTable1;

    Table() {

        p1=new JPanel();
        p1.setBackground(Color.red);
        p1.setVisible(true);
        p1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        final String[] headers = {"First Name","Last Name","Age"};
        final Object[][] data = {
                {"Kathy", "Smith",new Integer(25)},
        };

        jTable1 =new JTable(data, headers);
        final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTable1);

        p1.add(scrollPane);

        f=new JFrame("Home123");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(p1);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Table();
    }
}
```

P.S. Never use null-layout.