# get node value from JTree and display it in JTable using JButton

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, jtree

I know it's simple and stupid questions, since I am newbie don't know how to link.

I am trying to get a [node value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNibt.png) (file with path), and to push the node value into JTable using JButton - 'Add Files', have posted the code so far have tried, it doesn't give any error but it is not performing what I wanted, please give me directions on this, thanks.

How to get a node value from one function to another function, thanks

obtaining node value from JTree

```
    File root = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
    FileTreeModel model = new FileTreeModel(root);
    JTree tree = new JTree(model);
    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(tree);
    scrollpane.setBounds(10, 9, 304, 730);
    frmViperManufacturingRecord.getContentPane().add(scrollpane);


    tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
            File node = (File)e.getPath().getLastPathComponent();
            //System.out.println("You selected " + node);
            if (!node.isFile()) {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Please select the valid file to Add Files", "Not Valid File",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );
                //if (result == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION);
            }
            //else
        }
    });
```

trying push the node value into JTable

```
    //table just below Add Files button
    table_2 = new JTable();
    table_2.setBounds(324, 43, 713, 121);
    frmViperManufacturingRecord.getContentPane().add(table_2);
```

using JButton

```
    // Add files button
    JButton btnAddFiles_1 = new JButton("Add Files");
    btnAddFiles_1.setMnemonic('A');
    btnAddFiles_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            Object rowData[][] = { { "01.", node, }};
            Object columnNames[] = { "Sl.no", "File name"};
            JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
        }
    });
    btnAddFiles_1.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 12));
    btnAddFiles_1.setBounds(324, 9, 89, 23);
    frmViperManufacturingRecord.getContentPane().add(btnAddFiles_1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
btnAddFiles_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        Object rowData[][] = { { "01.", node, }};
        Object columnNames[] = { "Sl.no", "File name"};
        JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames); // new JTable that is not placed in the content pane
   }
});
```

Don't re-create the table itself as `table_2` has been created and placed already. Update its table model instead. For example:

```
btnAddFiles_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        Object rowData[][] = { { "01.", node, }};
        Object columnNames[] = { "Sl.no", "File name"};
        table_2.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames));
   }
});
```

---

#### Side notes

About this line:

```
table_2.setBounds(324, 43, 713, 121);
```

Swing is designed to work with [LayoutManagers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) and methods like `setBounds(...)`, `setLocation(...)` and `setXxxSize(...)` are discouraged. See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/)

In addition (thanks to @mKorbel comments):

```
frmViperManufacturingRecord.getContentPane().add(table_2);
```

Tables should be placed within a `JScrollPane` just like your tree is:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table_2);
frmViperManufacturingRecord.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
```

Comment: JTable should be into JScorllPane too -1 (plus isn't accesible in commments, not allowed here)

Comment: I've noted that too. But you can use 1+ instead (curious thing though) @mKorbel

Comment: looks like as comment can't start or ends with char +

Comment: We will have to start our comments saying "Plus one." instead of +1 :o) @mKorbel

Comment: Thanks @dic19, will work on it with your code. it worked, thank you so much for your time and help

Comment: Hi @dic19, for some reason I can't see the column header on JTable, is anything I am missing? thanks

Comment: [Probably the scroll pane](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2320812/1795530). @Java.beginner

Comment: Thanks @dic19, if I add JScrollPane as you have mentioned in the answer, when I run the application I can't see the JTable at all.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to clarify that you have to set the bounds to the scrollpane not the table anymore. @Java.beginner