# Table with JScrollPane won't show column headers

Tags: java, swing, header, jtable, jscrollpane

This `JTable` with `JScrollPane` won't show the column headers.

```
package jTable;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class Main {

    JFrame frame ;
    Main()
   {       
     frame = new JFrame() ;
     String [][] names  = {
             {"1000","yamen","develeoper"},
             {"2000","aymen","data entry"},
             {"3000","mohammed","teacher"}
             };

       String[]  header = {"ID","NAME","JOB"};     
       JTable   jtb = new JTable(names,header) ;        
       JScrollPane  s = new JScrollPane(jtb);

       jtb.setBounds(40,50,300,400);
       frame.add(jtb);

       frame.setSize(400, 500);
       frame.setVisible(true);
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*JTable won't show column headers*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2320812/230513).

Answer (score 4):

The scroll pane will display the header. Having created a `JScrollPane` with your `JTable`,

```
JTable jtb = new JTable(names, header);
JScrollPane s = new JScrollPane(jtb);
```

you probably meant,

```
frame.add(s);
```

See [*How to Use Tables: Adding a Table to a Container*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#show) for details.

[image: table image]

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a `TableModel` with the names and headers

```
tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(names, headers);
```

And then assign the `JTable` this `TableModel`

```
jtb.setModel(tableModel);
```

And then add a new `JScrollPane` to the frame

```
frame.add(new JScrollPane(jtb));
```

At least, this is how I did it in my program.